# Filtering with html content

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I am trying to put a select filter on a column with html content.

The filter finds the id's of the html strings but the table shows no records once I select a value in the filter.

See example here:
http://live.datatables.net/rabesuta/1/edit?html,js,output

relevant `td` content

```
<td><i id="Yes" class="fa fa-circle" style="color:green;font-size:20px;"></i></td>
```

yadcf setup:

```
 yadcf.init(table,[   
         {
           column_number: 0, 
           column_data_type: 'html', 
           html_data_type: 'id'            
         }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not really related to yadcf, but rather to datatables itself,

If you will feed the global datatables filter with the word *No* or *Yes* it wont show you any results - because it seems that it not looking inside the html attributes,

So what you can do is placing a hidden html element inside yours (with your desired serach value enclosed, like this

```
<td>
    <i id="No" class="fa fa-circle" style="color:red;font-size:20px;">
        <span class="hide">No</span>
    </i>
</td>
```

with the following css

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

and everything will work as expceted, [see working sample](http://live.datatables.net/yisusuzo/1/edit)

and you can even reduce your html and yadcf setup by removing the ids from the html and using a more simple yadcf setup, see [working sample N#2](http://live.datatables.net/pufamara/1/edit)

relevant code:

```
<td>
    <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:red;font-size:20px;">
        <span class="hide">No</span>
    </i>
</td>


 yadcf.init(table,[   
         {
           column_number: 0, 
           column_data_type: 'html'
         }
  ]);
```